# Setting up Home Studio, need advise on setup

Tags: home-studio, acoustics, studio, studio-design

I am setting up my home studio (I am mainly a music producer, produce hip hop / trap beats). My present setup is as shown in **image 3** which is not giving me the perfect results. I have 2 ideas that is **image 1** and **image 2**. Which one do you suggest I shall go ahead with? Any other suggestion/opinion appreciated

[image: Image 1 - Idea 1] [image: Image 2 - Idea 2]

[image: Image 3 - Present Setup]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: When you're trying to get a good sound in your room, 90% will be speaker placement and 10% will be materials/traps etc. Just start moving things around, get a mic and play some pink noise and sweeps, see what set up gets you closer to the one produced by the PC. Place your speakers and then try to "Treat" the resulting layout. You can see from Tetsujin's answer below, that experimentation with speaker placement can get you to places that you wouldn't think of.. But, in this topic, you want what works best! (also be very careful about your monitoring volume)

Answer (score 2):

In a tiny room like that, with unspecified materials, the quickest way to find out is to try it.

My optimum in a home studio ended up being this…

[image]

My ceiling is also partially sloped.  Room is approx 15'x12'x10'.
There is no real scientific rationale for this layout working. It just started out as the best way the gear fit in the room, but measurements proved it really wasn't a bad choice. An 'accidental' bass-trap is in the opposite corner, a rail full of hanging winter coats in a chimney-breast alcove.
Complete accident it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

As Tetsujin suggest, the best way to find out is to perform some measurements and tests.

Having to judge from just a sketch and speculating about the effectiveness of the material inside the room I would personally suggest using **image 1** as a starting point.

To justify my thoughts, it seems that in this image the setup looks a lot more like like a LEDE design (for more info on LEDE look [here](https://www.soundonsound.com/techniques/sos-guide-control-room-design)).

First of all, it seems that the early reflections seem to be controlled better there (unless I mistakenly assume those grey panels to be acoustic treatment).

Second, the late reflections from the back wall (I assume that curtains will attenuate sound just a wee bit) will be quite late to arrive and won't distort either the frequency response a lot, or the stereo image (up to a certain level of course). They will add to the spaciousness of the environment providing a somewhat live result (completely dry rooms have proven to not work very well for mixing purpose. This is one of the many reasons why people don't mix in anechoic chambers).

Finally, it seems that at this position, there is no difference in the acoustic treatment on the left and right side of the desk. If you effectively have "different environments" on your two sides, you will experience a really bad stereo image instability and haziness. In **image 2**, on the left side, you have some acoustic treatment, while on the right side you only have some curtains, which don't provide good acoustic control, thus you will experience increased early reflection levels on the right side compared to the left side creating spatial chaos (I may or may **not** be exaggerating here, this depends on the acoustic treatment of your room)!